# eXist-db and Saxon processor in production (licensing)

Tags: saxon, exist-db

I have no clue what is the version of Saxon used in the latest (and the next stable) version of eXist-db. I would like to use eXist in production and guess it would be quite right to pay the license. If so, I am not sure whether it is necessary to somehow update the version of Saxon (HE, PE, EE). If there is HE used, could I use that in production too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current "develop" branch -the be released as eXist-db 3.0- contains Saxon-HE-9.6.0-7; It is not possible though to just replace this JAR with a randomly selected version, the betterForm code has dependencies with this specific version of Saxon.

It should be possible to replace the HE version with an PE/EE jar but please check upfront  before purchasing.

For the future, the tight coupling between BetterForm and Saxon will be removed, it is on the roadmap.

Comment: If it would be possible to pay for the license and use the HE edition, it could solve my case. I am satisfied with the version used in eXist right now. Thanks.

Comment: If the HE version suits you and you meet the requirements of use for its open source license (Mozilla Public License v2), then you can continue to use that without purchasing a commercial license for PE or HE. However if you need PE or HE, then you will need to purchase a commercial license from Saxonica, see - http://www.saxonica.com/products/products.xml